# Dump content of JSON in specific format

Tags: python

I am need to actually create a Windows INI using Python scipt file of below format:

```
AGENTIP = 1.2.3.4,
VARFILE = C:\Users\output\temp.out
INFOFILE= C:\Users\output\info.out
SYNTEST = Run:Level1/Get
CMDMODE = RUNTESTSUITE
```

And Below is my Python code where I have the data in JSON string and then dump the content in a file:

```
def change_test_details(self, ver, level, grp):
    data = {"AGENTIP" : "1.2.3.4", "VARFILE" : "C:\\Users\\output\\temp.out", "INFOFILE" : "C:\\Users\\output\\info.out", "SYNTEST" :"Run:Level1/Get", "CMDMODE" :"RUNTESTSUITE"}
    data["SYNTEST"] = ver + ":" + level + "/" + grp
    with open("a.txt", 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile,indent=2)
```

When the method is called with below param:

"BETA"    "Level5"     "Set"

The final output if the file is

```
{
  "AGENTIP": "1.2.3.4",
  "VARFILE": "C:\\Users\\output\\temp.out",
  "INFOFILE": "C:\\Users\\output\\info.out",
  "SYNTEST": "\"BETA\":\"Level5\"/\"Set\"",
  "CMDMODE": "RUNTESTSUITE"
}
```

There is '{ .. }' braces and extra double quotes and '\' and expected value of SYNTEST should be **BETA:Level5/Set** ?

How can change the JSON string to required format?

Comment: `change_test_details("BETA", "Level5", "Set")` works as expected for me. Can you please share the exact call you make?

Comment: I am calling the script from Robotframework and when I log to console their values are "Beta" "Level5"  "Set"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**json.dump()** prints an object as a json formatted string. So when you dump that into outfile you get a json string in the file, which is how it's supposed to behave.

What you want is to iterate over the items and print them according to the format you want.

```py
def change_test_details(ver, level, grp):
    data = {"AGENTIP" : "1.2.3.4", "VARFILE" : "C:\\Users\\output\\temp.out", "INFOFILE" : "C:\\Users\\output\\info.out", "SYNTEST" :"Run:Level1/Get", "CMDMODE" :"RUNTESTSUITE"}
    data["SYNTEST"] = ver + ":" + level + "/" + grp
    with open("a.txt", 'w') as outfile:
        for k, v in data.items():
            outfile.write(f'{k} = {v}\n')

change_test_details("BETA", "Level5","Set")
```

When you run this, a.txt looks something like:

```
AGENTIP = 1.2.3.4
VARFILE = C:\Users\output\temp.out
INFOFILE = C:\Users\output\info.out
SYNTEST = BETA:Level5/Set
CMDMODE = RUNTESTSUITE
```